# Google map activity not found

Tags: android-studio, android-activity

When I open Android studio and creating new project, when I can't find googleMapsActivity.
Only  I found 4-5 basic activities like EmptyViewActivity, ResponsiveActivity, C++ activity...
Please help me how I can found googleMapsActivity  when I creating project.

I not able to create  google_maps_api.xml and google api kew link